# What is the site's policy on moderators revoking a user's request for deletion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-users

What is the site's policy on moderators revoking a user's request to delete their entire account? I wanted to be gone after 24 hours, but ~39 hours later, here I am.    I've already reapplied for account deletion, but is there a way to ensure profile deletion without having to try again for a third time?

Here is the relevant comment from the moderator:

> *"@Null I've canceled your account deletion. We need to talk before you continue with this. I am going out right now and won't be around immediately to talk. When are you available to talk? You and me in a chat room, we can make it private or not, your choice. Or you can talk to another moderator. Act in haste repent in leisure as they say. Honestly, I've been where you are and sometimes it's better to wait before quitting"*
>   ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389372/#comment727771_389377))

Comment: You don’t have to try again. No one is denying or revoking that right. It just takes a while (sometimes a week or more) to go through the process. There’s still a manual component for accounts with a history of content, so there’s a queue. Just be patient.

Comment: Just request deletion and leave. SE will get around to it eventually. There's probably a backlog

Comment: @Dan Bron The mod in question specifically told me they canceled by request for deletion.

Comment: @Null Oh, that’s weird. I’ve never heard of that happening before. Can you quote that mod message in your Q here? Or just go to the CMs directly, use the “contact us” link in the footer.

Comment: @Don Bron  I'd link to it, but the answer it was under has since been deleted. It was under this answer (I am specifically not naming names, so let's please not make it that. I just want to know if this is normal) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/11563547?group=1&status=2

Comment: @Null: We can't view your flags.

Comment: If you want us to see that, you'll have to screenshot it (or better - copy-paste the relevant reply)

Comment: It doesn't show any information that would really add to this, so I'm not going to post the screenshot of my flags.

Comment: @Zoe they told me they did it in a comment that is now deleted, so I can't see it any more. And then I had to go back and and do the deletion procedure again.

Comment: Mike, I know you are angry, but are you sure doing things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933115/pointer-to-root-node-of-b-tree-after-call-to-a-function-begins-pointing-to-a-chi) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57114884/how-can-i-list-contents-of-folders-with-cyrillic-font) are productive? Or the three unaccepts from earlier? Can't you chalk all these things off to a misunderstanding, wait a bit a and see if you feel the same in a week or so? Peace.

Comment: I couldn't think of a faster way to bleed off my points after being asked to stick around longer.

Comment: But "bleeding off your points" doesn't make your account disappear. Just makes it look like you want to disrupt the site. I have nothing against you. My advise, if you want to take it, just leave the site for a week or two, and if you continue feeling that way the, just ask for deletion an let it go. (BTW, the content won't be deleted, just your account).

Comment: It's not shaming you, at all. Do not interpret these things as an attack. I'm not showing anything private (I do not have the capability for that, I only can see your public actions). It's just that it shocked me that you had so little rep now when I remembered you had around 1k.

Comment: Frankly, I'm with yivi on this. Besides, if your account gets deleted, all rep events related to it are deleted as well. It's as if your account never existed... Opening bounties is quite pointless, then.

Comment: @yivi I actually mean, that unlike the other thread, you're not out of bounds to call that out.

Comment: **Mod Note** this is closed as the person is on a rage quit and shows no interest in finding solutions to anything.

Comment: @410: Oh, that's news to me, thanks. These specific bounties were cancelled, though.

Answer (score 19):

While it's not exactly standard procedure, the moderator in question informed you why they did it, and also informed you on how to contact them:

> [image]
>   ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389372/#comment727771_389377))

There was nothing "malicious" about that. The moderator wanted to prevent you from making a overhasty decision, because account deletion is *quite* permanent. They were trying to be helpful.

If you're still certain you want to delete your account, just contact that moderator, or re-submit a deletion request.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer Cerbrus.

Comment: @YvetteColomb I don't really know the deal with chat rooms yet, and I want my account deleted as soon as possible. Can that just happen already?

Comment: @Null I can hardly do that now can I? It will look like I'm trying to get rid of you. fwiw I have been in your position a lot and rage quite a lot over the years. I probably understand you more than you realise. I wanted to pull you back to calm down and work it out. I'm sorry you felt shamed and I was probably too hard on you. My stance has been to stamp down on people shaming mods, employees and other users and ironically, you now feel shamed by me! It wasn't the intended purpose. Quite the opposite. There's some stories i could tell you, but you want to leave and time is short.

Comment: I suspect the other storied lead to a prejudgment. At least, please don't block my account deletion again.

Comment: @Null chatrooms are just like loads of comments, but we can also make them private so no one else can see it, for moderation purposes.

Comment: @Null of course it did! And for that I apologise. I wanted to have a chance for us to work this out and no, I won't block it. I was trying to be nice... didn't work hey? I deleted the answer and I've apologised. I went about that the wrong way. Why don't you cancel your deletion request and take a breather. You know what? I will tell you something. I felt like leaving today too! Sometimes the stress can be too much on top of other things in life. People told me to sleep on it. Can you try and do the same thing? We can get rid of your account at any time. It's better to try and work things out.

Comment: I just went through this last week! All the negativity and downvotes and spite, and um, closed questions - just ugh. But... I read up a bunch this past weekend and tried to understand where people were coming from and users/moderators get frustrated too and like everyone says - we're all HUMAN! We all make mistakes and may unintentionally send tone in spades or even be outright rude, but I now understand the *intention* of the site and the moderators better. All the emotions flying around is difficult, but I just had to change my frame of mind and understand the paradigm shift that is SO...

Comment: It's different here - way different - if you hadn't read up on all that first. Very unexpected, and learning how to ask a question is about like learning a new programming language! It's painful! But I understand why they do what they do and the reason they do it. Mods actively update content here to keep it all fresh and tidy. And that may seem rude sometimes, but ya gotta understand the reasoning behind it all and not get upset (like I was the last few weeks)... That all said, I wanted to leave too, but am gonna stick around - and stay positive...

Comment: @sfors: It’s awesome to read that you had a change of heart. I remember your meta interaction here... It wasn’t exactly optimal ;-) Just one note: please be aware that creating a new account to get around restrictions placed on your first account is frowned upon, and can result in the second account being banned. A better course of action would be to improve the questions that got you question-banned.